# Updating jQuery from 1.6 to 1.7 broke my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently updated jQuery from 1.6 to 1.7 and the following has stopped working:

## Question:

None of the elements are being updated, is there something wrong with my code? Or am I using something which could have been affected through updating jQuery?

### JavaScript function call to update a set of elements using jQuery:

```
function NGUIM_updateCard(data)
{      
  var id = data._id;
  var deadline = data.deadline;
  var description = data.description;
  var roi = data.roi;
  var sp = data.sp;
  var value = data.value;
  var type = data.type;
  var title = data.title;
  var developers = data.developers;

  console.log(
    id + "\n" +
    deadline + "\n" +
    description + "\n" +
    roi + "\n" +
    sp + "\n" +
    value + "\n" +
    type + "\n" +
    title + "\n" +
    developers + "\n"
  );

  var developerString = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < developers.length; i++)
  {
    if(i == 0){
      developerString += developers[i] + ',';
    } else {
      developerString += developers[i];
    }
  }

  var card = $("span[data-id="+id+"]").parent().parent();
      card.find('.card-title').text(title);
      card.find('.card-description').text(description);


  card.find('.card-attributes')
      .attr('data-deadline', deadline)
      .attr('data-sp', sp)
      .attr('data-value', value)
      .attr('data-roi', roi)
      .attr('data-devs', developerString);


  card.find('.card-attr-deadline').text(deadline);
  card.find('.card-attr-value').text("Value: " + value);
  card.find('.card-attr-sp').text("SP: " + sp);
  card.find('.card-attr-roi').text("ROI: " + roi);

  if(card.hasClass("improvement")){
    if(type == "fix"){
      card.removeClass("improvement")
          .addClass(type);
    } else if (type == "story"){
      card.removeClass("improvement")
          .addClass(type);
    }
  } else if (card.hasClass("fix")){
    if(type == "improvement"){
      card.removeClass("fix")
          .addClass(type);
    } else if (type == "story"){
      card.removeClass("fix")
          .addClass(type);          
    }
  } else {
    if(type == "fix"){
      card.addClass(type);
    } else if (type == "improvement"){
      card.addClass(type);
    }
  }
}
```

Console.logs output their expected values, however the elements aren't being updated. No errors are appearing inside the Chrome developer console.

Output from `console.log(card);`:

```
<li class="story">
  <header>
    <h1 class="card-title">abcd</h1>
    <p class="card-attr-deadline">10/10/2010</p>
    <span class="edit-card"></span>
    <span class="card-developers"></span>
    <span class="card-attributes" data-value="5" data-roi="1.00" data-sp="5" data-deadline="10/10/2010" data-id="0WndpeAmnzWRVQw15zizanU0" data-devs="a,brownj2"></span>
  </header>
  <section class="card-description">...</section>
  <p class="card-attr-sp">SP: 5</p>
  <p class="card-attr-value">Value: 5</p>
  <p class="card-attr-roi">ROI: 1.00</p>
</li>
```

Comment: @gurung yes, only the above function isn't working.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted even uses jQuery. Edit: Unless you are talking about jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Ah, i always miss that. sorry!

Comment: Why is it people come to SO with a question that says "it broke" and offer no more info than that?  How did it break?  What exactly stopped working?  Are there any errors in the error console?  Did you step through the code in the debugger to see where it went haywire?  Come on people - this is elementary javascript troubleshooting - learn to use the tools.  Once you figure out where the problem is, feel free to ask a much more specific question is you don't know how to fix the problem you found.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using Node.js, and i've stepped through it using console.logs. I've said that it stopped working when updating jQuery, I've mentioned that there are no errors in the console, and i've provided a console log showing the output! what more can I give apart from the whole source lol?

Comment: You need to learn elemental debugging.  Step through it in the debugger and see what isn't changing.  Examine in the DOM inspector and see which classes are not being changed that you expect.  Find out exactly which step in the code is not doing what you expect and then you know where to look more specifically for the problem.  You don't tell us anything about what result you're expecting, but not seeing - all you say it is broke.  Remember, we don't know what the result is supposed to look like so you have to tell us what change you're expecting, but not getting.

Comment: What browser is this not working in?  I can get it to work with both 1.6.4 and 1.7 in Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/hSJLj/ and http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/yxedS/

Comment: @BrettPontarelli Google Chrome 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
card.find('.card-attributes')
  .attr('data-deadline', deadline)
  .attr('data-sp', sp)
  .attr('data-value', value)
  .attr('data-roi', roi)
  .attr('data-devs', developerString);
```

to

```
card.find('.card-attributes').first()
  .data('deadline', deadline)
  .data('sp', sp)
  .data('value', value)
  .data('roi', roi)
  .data('devs', developerString);
```

Comment: didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did you try `var card = $("span[data-id='"+id+"']").parent().parent();` too? (note the extra single quotes)

Comment: I'll give it a shot, just out of curiosity is it better practice to use .first() followed by .data?

Comment: Nothing special about it. I use it when I want to ensure my thing affects only one element. Shouldn't be special. The `data()` usage is a best practice though.